# Display Code from ckeditor to website properly, django

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

So i want to display well formatted code with syntax coloring as we see in stackoverflow, in my blog. While I paste my code in ckeditor under the code section, it is pretty good and well formatted. Like in the picture below.
[image]

I want something like that to appear on my website. But when I save it and view it on my website, I get formatted but not syntax colored code. Like the picture below.
[image]

Am I doing anything wrong here. Please help

Comment: The code is well formatted in both cases, you are talking about the syntax coloring. CKEditor uses syntax coloring when displaying code parts. I guess what you're saving on your website is only the text of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want code/syntax highlighting. There is a [ckeditor plugin](https://github.com/dbrain/ckeditor-syntaxhighlight) for that or you can use a [Pygments](http://pygments.org/), python syntax highlighter. Here is a short tutorial how to create [django filter with Pygments](http://www.blacksailor.com/en/blog/code-highlighting-in-django-templates-using-pygments-2/)